# Exception caught by rendering library | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

What I want to do,
first list view scroll horizontally and the second one and full-screen scroll vertically.
(When the user scrolls vertically, the first listview will be hidden)

Like Facebook feed screens
the first list looks like a story row,
the second list looks like posts.

This picture shows what I want to do simply

[image]

I tried,
my code here :

```
Stack(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                            snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Demo Headline 2',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                          snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80, right: 10),
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      elevation: 100,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add');
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        size: 32,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
```

My code shows this error

Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#90e8f relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and `shrinkWrap: true,` in 2nd Listview

Listview Widget:

```
   Expanded(child:
     ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,//add this line
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
        snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
       ),
     ),
    ),
```

Full Code:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 100.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        'Demo Headline 2',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    elevation: 100,
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add');
    },
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.add,
      size: 32,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
);
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: It didn't work. also, showing the error. 

Comment: what was the error?and you want to display floatButton is corner of the screen?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#59a8e relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Stack

Comment: Check my updated answer and remove `SingleChildScrollView` and Wrap your 2nd `Listview` inside `Expanded` widget

Comment: This time, error is same. but it shows The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

Comment: I can't understand what you say?

Comment: Error showing like this 

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#417a0 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

Comment: 1st thing tell me are you use floatButton in whole screen?

Comment: Yes. even if the user scroll vertically
it should show. Every time when the user in the feed screen.

Comment: @HoRiz I have update my answer just replace my widgets to your widgtes

Comment: I use StreamBuilder in body. So, It shows that error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249937/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-horiz).