# Horizontal ListView.builder inside a Vertical ScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do,

(in below how I tried)

[image]

My try:

```
Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("posts")
              .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            //connection no problem
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                        snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
```

It didn't work. showing this error:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#aa89e relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold

Comment: If you saw my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74596193/13997210) this looks same as above design

Comment: yes. Got it. But, it scrolls itself only.
When the user scrolls down, the first list does not hide. it always stays there like an app bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Expanded` in `column` that wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView`, try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100 + 12 + 12,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 150,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```